# How to add a non-Android Java package to the Android development environment?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

So far I have been using in tutorials, examples and sample code only packages that came pre-installed with the Android SDK.

Now, I want to add a non-Android package (e.g. Jsoup).

What's the proper way of doing that (so that it becomes available to *all* projects)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it to a project by right clicking on your project in Eclipse and choose Build Path and Add External Archive. Select the jar to add it to your build path and it will be included in any apk you create.

One caveat is that if the jar may use part of the JDK that doesn't exist in Android.

Comment: Thanks, that's already helpful. Is there a way to make it available to **all** projects? (i.e. without having to righ-click and add it to each and every project)

Comment: @regex No. You will have to add it to each project.

Comment: I don't recommend doing the "available to all projects" bit as it detaches your project's dependencies from the project. But if you must... Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JRE's -> select -> Edit. If you see multiple JREs, make sure that you edit the one that your projects are using.

Comment: @Konstantin Komissarchik Thanks!